# How do I include an empty directory in a maven assembly?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In what must be a common occurence, I need to include an empty directory in an assembly. In my case it is logs/.

I've tried different variations in the assembly descriptor like:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>doesntexist</include>
  </includes>
  <outputDirectory>/logs</outputDirectory>
  <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
</fileSet>
```

and the directory just gets pruned.

I tried to exclude as well, but that still included lots of stuff:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>*</exclude>
  </excludes>
  <outputDirectory>/logs</outputDirectory>
  <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
</fileSet>
```

Answer (score 52):

This always works for me:

```
<fileSets>
  <fileSet>
    <directory>.</directory>
    <outputDirectory>logs</outputDirectory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>*/**</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: thanks for his usefull sample. In addition, if your input 'directory` rely on a build subdirectory, don't forget to forward empty directories at resources step too: cf.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605747/maven-how-to-include-empty-directories

Answer (score 19):

Courtesy, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605747/maven-how-to-include-empty-directories/2605774#2605774) and with some trial and error, the following one seems to work for me...

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/main/assembly</directory>
  <outputDirectory>/logs</outputDirectory>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>*</exclude>
  </excludes>
</fileSet>
```

The key seems to be to ensure that `<directory>` tag specifies a *valid/existing* folder, which *does not have any subfolders*.

Comment: If your directory contains folders you can exclude all of them (and all files) using `<exclude>**/*</exclude>`.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Christopher's worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>./EMPTY_DIRECTORY_NAME</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/REQUIRED_DIRECTORY_NAME in Assembly </outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

e.g.

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>./Logs</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/Feed</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

In this case even though there are some content inside Logs directory, it will not be included in assembled binary in Feed directory.