# Can I create empty directories while packaging using maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to create empty directory structure while doing the packaging using maven-assembly-plugin. I am successful in including all the files, but not creating the empty ones,

```
opt/SP/myprod/bin/*  (contains files)
opt/SP/myprod/lib/*  (contains files)
opt/SP/myprod/conf/* (contains files)
var/SP/myprod/run    (Empty directories)
var/SP/myprod/log    (Empty directories)
var/SP/myprod/tmp    (Empty directories)
```

The below one is my assembly file,

```
<id>stage</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<fileSets filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${run.dir}</directory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${tmp.dir}</directory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${log.dir}</directory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/config</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${install.dir}/config</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/bin</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${install.dir}/bin</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/images</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${install.dir}/images</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/package-scripts</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${install.dir}/package-scripts</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${install.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>myfile.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${install.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>

</fileSets>
```

So, I tried the simple "directory" tag as recommended in one of the blog, but no luck.

Could any one help me please?

Comment: Last time I had to package an empty dir using maven, I ended leaving an empty file name `DO_NOT_REMOVE` in it (being sure I will never have a *real* file with that name in it ...)

Comment: Try defining the <outputDirectory> for those filesets.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - hmm, seems like an option. outputDirectory tag was already tried and even specifying a valid directory adding an exclussion filter. All does not seems a clean solution. Thinking of adding the ant-run-plugin and can create folder using ant commands mkdir.

Answer (score 13):

Note that @khmarbaise's answer will not exclude all subfolders, you need to use a stronger wildcard:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet> <!-- Create empty directory -->
        <outputDirectory>coredumps</outputDirectory>
        <excludes><exclude>**/*</exclude></excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Found at [How do I include an empty directory in a maven assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909183/how-do-i-include-an-empty-directory-in-a-maven-assembly)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a thing like this here:

```xml
<fileSets>
  <fileSet>
     <outputDirectory>/an-other-empty-folder</outputDirectory>
     <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
     <excludes>
       <exclude>*</exclude>
     </excludes>
  </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: Need to use <exclude>**/*</exclude> otherwise files in sub directories might get copied to the folder.