# Empty directories are not copied during build from `scr/main/webapp`

Tags: java, maven

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605747/maven-how-to-include-empty-directories/2605769?noredirect=1#comment30346002_2605769) prompted me to post a follow up question. During a maven build, empty directories are not copied from `src/main/webapp`, even though I have set the `pom.xml` to include empty directories:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How come empty directories are not copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is due to bug [MWAR-128](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-128) in maven. The solution is to upgrade Maven to [r1498124](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1498124). Alternately, you can include a placeholder file (ex. empty.tmp) and filter it like so:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>**/empty.tmp</packagingExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just met the same problem. This worked for me:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories> <!-- since 2.4 -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Your method didn't work because that "src/main/webapp" was not a resource directory.