# Copy empty directory from test resources in Maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, pom.xml

Based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605769/2212098) I am trying to copy an **empty directory** from test resources folder in *Maven* based project to the test build output but with no luck. I have already been successfully using **`maven-resource-plugin`** for copying basic resources so I tried to add another execution part for test resources like this to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resource</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-test-resource</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also tried to define it in build section like this:

```xml
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

but it also didn't help.

All files and non-empty directories gets correctly copied but the single empty directory doesn't.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Can you just put a dotfile in there?

Comment: @chrylis What do you mean by dotfile?

Comment: could you run with `-X` and post entire output here

Comment: @JigarJoshi here is the output at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/s7DtTfJi) Don't know if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved it!

The problem is that element `<includeEmptyDirs>` was in the wrong place in the plugin section. it should be a part of **plugin configuration**, NOT part of **execution configuration**.

Also I changed goal of `copy-test-resource` to **`testResources`** and `outputDirectory` to **`${project.build.testOutputDirectory}`**

So the correct plugin section is following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resource</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-test-resource</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```