# Maven doesn't copy empty directories to webapps folder while creating war file

Tags: java, maven

I have he following structure of a maven web application

[image]

When I execute `mvn install` command it's creating war file but if you will look in `target directory/sureportal` you can easily see that lots of sub folders inside `webapps` directory are missing. What is wrong?

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nokia</groupId>
  <artifactId>sureportal</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>sureportal Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>sureportal</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `maven-war-plugin` and configure to include empty folders.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: exactly the same solution as mine. See the comments in my POM fragment ... but no problem

Comment: @JimHawkins Sorry to say your code tag have plenty of thing which make little bit clumsy this answer specific to answer. Any how thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of sbaitmangalkar, insert the `maven-war-plugin` to the build section of your POM:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-  if you don't have a web.xml, otherwise "true" -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>
                <includes>**/*</includes>

                <!-- if want your web files to be filterd -->
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>

                        <!-- only if needed in your project -->
                        <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>context.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This tells the build process explicitly what to do.

Comment: This should not be required by default.

Comment: @SaifAsif what you say sounds coorect. But without this section, in my project there is the same issue as reported by Subodh Joshi

Comment: What about if the folder which is not copying when creating war is empty even then maven will copy the folders?

Comment: yes, if you insert `<includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>` like I did in my answer, even empty folders will be copied

Comment: Ok do you mean like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605747/maven-how-to-include-empty-directories But this will work for resource directory not for other

Comment: @SubodhJoshi - you've written _"Can you please add this in to your question"_ . There is no question of mine.

Comment: @JimHawkins Sorry i added another comment

Comment: in my test project, this worked : `<includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>` , not only for eresource folders

Comment: This will work for `resource` directory not others and you need `resource` plugin in your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mvn clean install`. This will clear your compiled files first and ensures that all of it is compiled from scratch. Please check this thread for more details [how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018701/how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install)

Good luck.