# Maven: Dynamic Web Project's WAR is not including a folder that was created manually in WebContent/WEB-INF

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have written a REST-API using JAX-RS. For that I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, and than converted it into a Maven project.
I want my logger folder to be `WEB-INF/logs/loggerFile.out`.
So I created a folder in my `WebContent/WEB-INF/logs`.
But now when I am packaging it in a WAR, the `logs` folder is missing in the packages WAR as as in the `target/MyProj/WEB-INF`..there is no `log` folder there as well.
I tried creating the folder inside `target/MyProj/WEB-INF` manually, but still its not available in the WAR file.
(I am viewing the content inside the WAR file using 7-zip).
I am doing all this on my Windows-7.
Please help
[image]

Comment: Sorry but that does not make sense to have a logger output in `WEB-INF/logs/loggerFile.out.` cause that is part of your WAR file...which in other words is not writeable..and shouldn't be...you should use a configuration from your server...

Comment: Could it be because your directory is empty when you build your war? Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605747/maven-how-to-include-empty-directories